# Higher order function on a nested array

Tags: swift, higher-order-functions

So I believe I'm on the right track here. Lets say I have a data type: `[[String:Double]]`

and I want to add all of the Doubles / value qualities. How would I go about it...

So far I have...

```
var slices: [NewestAttempt] {
        let data: [[String:Double]] = [["Bost" : 80], ["Craig" : 70], ["Dans" : 50]]
        let total = 0
        for array in arrays {
            data.reduce{ $0[total].reduce(0) {$0 + $1.value }}
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: So you want a single `Double`, which is the sum of all the `Double`s?

Comment: What's not working with the current code? What's `NewestAttempt`?

Comment: Yes, to start, then I will need a single array of tuples - String and Double pairs, but I think once I see the `.reduce` function giving me the single Double total, I should be able to figure out how to do the rest

Comment: @Cristik

`Contextual closure type '(Int, [String : Double]) throws -> Int' expects 2 arguments, but 1 was used in closure body`

Which is confusing to me because I am using $0 and $1

Comment: Well, the `$1` is from the inner closure, in the outer closure you are using only `$0`. You also didn't specify the initial value for the outer `reduce` call.

Comment: `for array in arrays`: What is `arrays`? What happened to `array`?

Comment: Accidentally left that part out, arrays was just an array of arrays

Comment: @matt [[String:Double]]

Comment: Well don't leave part out. Do not show us meaningless gibberish and say Fix this for me.

Comment: Also your data is not an array of arrays. It is an array of single key dictionaries! But that suggests you should be using a struct instead.

Comment: Duly noted, unnecessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this -

```
let data: [[String:Double]] = [["Bost" : 80], ["Craig" : 70], ["Dans" : 50]]
var total: Double = 0
for packet in data {
    for (key, value) in packet {
        total += value
    }
}

print(total)
```

#### UPDATE

Using `reduce`

```
let data: [[String:Double]] = [["Bost" : 80], ["Craig" : 70], ["Dans" : 50]]
var total: Double = 0
for packet in data {
    total += packet.values.reduce(0, +)
}
print(total)
```

Comment: Awesome, I see I was missing a for loop.. I'm curious though, is there anyway to just use `.reduce` on `data` to get the same result

Comment: See the **UPDATE**.

Comment: Without a `for` loop: `data.reduce(0) { $1.reduce($0, +) }`

Comment: or simply `data.flatMap(\.values).reduce(0,+)`